# How to Feed my y with the shapes of (16578, 10, 26)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have been experimenting with Tensorflow. Is there a way to feed my `y` which has the shapes `(16578, 10, 26)` to my model?

The goal of my experiment is to create a word generator where for example I input the word `stop` it will output `go`. For it I first tokenized and padded my inputs and labels in character forms:
e.g. for the `input` = ['s', 't', 'o', 'p'] equivalents to [19, 15, 20, 16] then add padding = [0, 0, 0, 19, 15, 20, 16]

and for the output I made the data transformation to this `output` = ['g', 'o'] equivalents to [7, 15] add padding = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 15] and then for one hot (26 for the letters) = [[0,0,0...0], [0,...,0] ..., [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,..,0], [0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,...,0]]

Basically my `y` is composed of:

- `10` : for the padding sequences
- `26` : for the one hot encoding per letter per each padding

Therefore, it has one hot inside another one hot

Here is the basic FFNN model:

```
# Initialize the FFNN model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(23,)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(26)
])

# Initialize the loss function
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
loss_fn(y_train[:1][0], predictions).numpy()
```

And I have been receiving this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-211-7c9725bc1eef> in <module>()
----> 1 loss_fn(y_train[:1][0], predictions).numpy()

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py in assert_is_compatible_with(self, other)
   1132     """
   1133     if not self.is_compatible_with(other):
-> 1134       raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))
   1135 
   1136   def most_specific_compatible_shape(self, other):

ValueError: Shapes (10, 26) and (1, 10) are incompatible
```

Comment: What exactly is your goal, what shall the outcome be?

Comment: My goal is to actually build something like a word generator where for example if I input `stop` it will output `go` I'll try to edit my post, thank you for this!

Comment: You could make this way more simple using sparse_categorical_crossentropy as loss. Then you would not need to use one-hot encodings but integers as y, which makes your data more slim

Comment: I have actually tried this at first, however it gives me this error ```ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (10,)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (1, 10)).```